# I want to get my toString method to print all the information of the objects in my array list but I am getting the output with [] brackets

Tags: java, object, oop, arraylist, tostring

For my code, I have tried using a toString method which I am not sure if is the best way to display information for objects in an array list. I wanted to try a normal method and then just call it but how would I do that for every object that I created in the array list? Is there a better way to approach this? This is what I have so far but the output prints the info with the [] brackets which I do not want. What is the correct way to display array list information of objects? Any help or advice would be appreciated.

`EmailApp.java`

```
package emailapp;
import java.util.*;

public class EmailApp 
{

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        String firstName;
        String lastName;
        int numEmployees;
        
        
        ArrayList<Email> list = new ArrayList<>();
        
        //user input
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("How many employees would you like to add?");
        
        numEmployees = keyboard.nextInt();
        keyboard.nextLine();      //consume newline left over after nextInt
        
        while(numEmployees <=0 || numEmployees >= 1000)
        {
            System.out.println("Your number of employees is a little rediculous don't you think? Try again.");
            numEmployees = keyboard.nextInt();
            keyboard.nextLine();      //consume newline left over after nextInt
        }
        
        
        for(int i = 0; i < numEmployees; i++)
        {
            System.out.println("What is new users first name?: ");
            
            firstName = keyboard.nextLine();
            
            System.out.println("What is new users last name?: ");
            
            lastName = keyboard.nextLine();
            
            //create object
            list.add(new Email(firstName, lastName));
            System.out.println(list);
        }
        
        
        //If youd like you can mess around with the setAltEmail or changePass method
    }
    
    
    
}
```

`Email.java`

```
package emailapp;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Email 
{
    //Attributes
    
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String department;
    private String password;
    private final int DEFAULTPASSWORDLENGTH = 10;
    private String email;
    private String alternateEmail;
    private int mailboxCapacity = 500;
    private String companySuffix = "company.com";
    
    
    //constructor. for first name last name
    public Email(String firstName, String lastName)
    {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        //System.out.println("EMAIL CREATED: " + this.firstName + " " + this.lastName);
        
        //Call a method asking for the department - return the department
        this.department = setDepartment();
        
        System.out.println("Department: " + this.department);
        
        //Call a method that returns a random password
        this.password = randomPassword(DEFAULTPASSWORDLENGTH);
        System.out.println("Your password is: " + this.password);
        
        //Combine elements to generate email
        email = firstName.toLowerCase() + "." + lastName.toLowerCase() + "@" + department + "." + companySuffix;
        System.out.println("Your email is: " + email);
        
    }
    
    //ask for the department
    private String setDepartment()

    {
        System.out.println("Enter the users department: ");
        System.out.println("Enter 1: For Sales\nEnter 2: For Development:\nEnter 3: for Accounting:\nEnter 0: For none");
        System.out.println("Enter Choice: ");
        //User choice for department
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        int departmentChoice = keyboard.nextInt();
        
        if(departmentChoice == 1)
        {
            return "sales";
        }
        else if(departmentChoice == 2)
        {
            return "development";
        }
        else if(departmentChoice == 3)
        {
            return "accounting";
        }
        else
        {
            return "none";
        }
        
    }
    
    //generate a random password
    private String randomPassword(int length)
    {
        String passwordSet ="ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!@$&";
        char[] password = new char[length];
        
        for(int i =0; i < length; i++)
        {
            int rand = (int)(Math.random() * passwordSet.length()); //rand = number between 1 and passwordSet length String
            password[i] = passwordSet.charAt(rand);                 //picks out a random char from string and assigns to each element in array
            
        }
        return new String (password);   //Returning a String instead of individual characters
    }
    
    //set the mailbox capacity
    public void setMailBoxCapacity(int capacity)
    {
        this.mailboxCapacity = capacity;
    }
    //set the alternate email
    public void setAlternateEmail(String altEmail)
    {
        this.alternateEmail = altEmail;
    }
    //change the password
    public void changePassword(String password)
    {
        this.password = password;
    }
    
    public int getMailboxCapacity()
    {
        return mailboxCapacity;
    }
    public String getAlternateEmail()
    {
        return alternateEmail;
    }
    public String getPassword()
    {
        return password;
    }
    
    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return "DISPLAY NAME: " + firstName + " " + lastName
                +"COMPANY EMAIL: " + email +
                "MAILBOX CAPACITY: " + mailboxCapacity + "mb";
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Printing the list by calling the list's toString will add the brackets.  To exercise more control. iterate over the list and print each element individually.

Comment: Instead of `println(list)`, use `println(String.join(",", list))`.  See [the documentation of String.join](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#join(java.lang.CharSequence,java.lang.Iterable)).

Comment: You can also use List::foreach method: list.foreach(System.out::println).

Answer (score 1):

Calling the println over a list will call the "toString" method of the List class.

What you want is to iterate over the list and call the toString of each Email object.

There are a lot of ways to do that but IMO the easiest one is to use the List::forEach method passing a reference to println:

```
list.forEach(System.out::println);
```